# Send answer back or route to another actor

Tags: java, scala, akka, reactive-programming

I'm doing my first steps with Akka and Scala. The scala doesn't matter for this question, could also be java.

My little program:

- Collects some Data (A)
- Does some calculation (B)
- And stores the result in a Table (C)

I see two or better three different approaches to design my actors. (A) sends a message to an actor for (B) but then we could choose between different approaches:

1. (B) sends an Answer back to (A)
2. (B) sends it to a third actor for the persistence (C)
3. ((B) stores the data himself in the db)

Which one is best practice? I would tend to the second. The third I put in brackets because I dislike. I like smaller parts, kind of: "Do one thing and do it right"

Thanks for your comments,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

When designing a solution with actors you should ask yourself how you would solve this with actual people. Who would do which task?
Worker actors should only do a single task. State actors should only concern about their state.
In your case ask yourself who wants the data to be collected (and what data), who is responsible for the calculation (are there different calculations?), who is storing the result and how wants that result to be stored?
Success.